# Performance of "select * from where 'datetime' >= NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH"

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm developing an application about mathematics questions and answer. For each member there's a history of questions.

For simplicity, the question table is something like the below:

```
question_idx(int,PK) | subject(varchar) | level(varchar) | reg_date(datetime,INDEX)
```

I want to select question that is less than 6 months ago. The query is:

```
SELECT * FROM QUESTION WHERE reg_date >= NOW() - 6 MONTH;
```

Is this query best optimized?

Comment: My question is this query is working as your expected output?

Comment: This tends more in the direction off code review

Comment: What does you query execution plan tell you?

Comment: explain said 'using where'

Comment: If you want to select all the columns from the table then it's highly likely that you cannot improve this query. Your query is sargable and you table is indexed on the only predicate. It's always better to state the columns you want to select explicitly. Whether infrastructure or data structure changes might improve things requires a huge amount of extra information about your environment.

Comment: Can you show the actual full EXPLAIN output?

One possible reason for not seeing "Using index" n the query plan could be that the majority of rows are from less than six months ago anyway. The heuristic for this is roughly: if more than two thirds of the rows are matched according to the optimizer estimates, it is faster to do a linear scan of the table instead of reading rows in index order, which would cause random IO ...

Comment: How long does the query take?  How often will you run the query?  In other words, why do you need _this_ query optimized?